# Wordpress – not including header/footer in AJAX request

Tags: ajax, wordpress

In ProcessWire, when making an AJAX request, you can set this in the a template file:

```
<?php if (!$config->ajax) include('./head.inc'); ?>
```

Is there an equivalent for Wordpress?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a $_GET parameter

```
function ajax_query() {
    // Return normally if the ajax query isn't set
    if ( ! isset( $_GET['_pjax'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    set_query_var( 'ajax', 'true' );
}

add_filter( 'template_redirect', 'ajax_query' );
```

and then just make your JS AJAX call with the parameter as `/page/?ajax=true`.

In the template:

```
$is_ajax_query  = get_query_var( 'ajax' );

if ( $is_ajax_query && 'true' === $is_ajax_query) :
    get_header();
endif;
```

As far as the other answer, I don't know if the `wp_doing_ajax` function would get called on just a JS request. I've never tried it and there isn't much documentation. I don't know how WordPress would know it's an AJAX request. To WordPress, it would just look like a normal get request I would think. So the parameter will work.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am using PJAX to handle my AJAX requests and it looks like it passes this in the `XHR request: 
XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost/Sites/dev/contact/?_pjax=section.context".

Comment: Ok, that's fine too. I changed the code to check for `_pjax` instead of `ajax`. If you just want the section and not a page I can add an example of getting a template part in a template based on what is passed to `_pjax`.

Comment: That's great. I also found out you could use if (!isset($_SERVER["HTTP_X_PJAX"])) too but will mark yours as the answer as it's more helpful to understand what is going on. Thanks!

Comment: Also, You don't need the template part of the example. In the template redirect instead of the query var you can use `get_template_part` and just load the part you want based on the _pjax value and call `exit()` if that part is all you want.